# What test to do when two linear regression models are different sample sizes?

Tags: r, regression, sample-size

I have two linear regressions models in r. The first model pits temperature against respiration for adult plankton, the second model pits the same variables (temperature against respiration) for juvenile plankton. However my sample size for the juvenile plankton is smaller than that of the adult sample, so I cannot run anova in r.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what test I can do to see if there's a significant difference between the two regressions?

Comment: You seem to be misusing ANOVA, even if the sample sizes were equal. What is the goal of your work?

Comment: I want to see if temperature affects the respiration rate of a plankton species at two different life-stages, and more importantly to see if there is a difference in respiration rates between the two life-stages. I have done two separate linear regression models for the two life-stages, and now I'm trying to compare the two together to see if there's a difference between them. I hope that makes sense, my stats knowledge is really poor.

Comment: The typical way to do this wild involve writing one regression equation that includes both data sets and a predictor (independent) variable that says the group to which the observation brings, plus an interaction variable between the group variable and the respiration. (The term would be something like ANCOVA with an interaction.) Can you do that and then see if the software output makes sense?// You might want to consider learning some basics about statistics before you jump into complicated problems.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is temperature, and respiration is respiration, so these measurements on different types of plankton shouldn't matter. Thus, stack the data sets, set $y$=temp, $x_1$=resp, and $x_2$=0 or 1 (0-juv, 1-adult) and $x_3=x_1 * x_2$, which is an "interaction" term.  Next, regress $y$ on  the 3 $x$-variables.  If $x_3$ is significant, i.e., $abs(Z)>1.96$, or $P<0.05$, then the slopes for both groups are unequal.  In other words, the linear dependency of temp on resp is significantly different between the groups.

Comment: There can be more to it (particularly the emphasis on $p<0.05$), but this is the gist. // The interaction is key!

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. Taking into account your suggestion on stacking the data sets, my script for multiple regression in r is as follows:

y <- reg$ Temperature, 
x1 <- reg$ Respiration, 
x2 <- reg$ Stage, 
x3 <- x1 * x2, 
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2+ x3, data=reg)
summary(model). 

I think this is right?.   
The p-value for x3 = 0.0131 so it is significantly different between the groups.